# Permission to access chrome://thumb/*

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm developing an google chrome extension. In there I would like to get the cached thumbnail images of topsites.

when I access a url like `chrome://thumb/http://www.google.com/` I can see the thumbnail. But in my extension it shows that

```
Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://thumb/https://www.google.com/
```

Is there a way to access these thumbnail images from chrome extension?

Comment: No, not yet: [Issue 11854: Extensions should be allowed to load some chrome:// URLs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=11854)

Comment: @Andreas But I'm able to access "chrome://favicon/*". Still no way to access chrome://thumb/* ?

Answer (score 2):

Add "**chrome://favicon/**" to permissions part in manifest file then you can get access favicon from your extension scripts. It will work fine with Browser Action, , Page Action but It will not work with content scripts that you inject to other pages.

Let take a look at [my extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-focus-tabs/blecebkjfbkpannnmajllilknpccheak). I use that feature also.